# Wiring 4+ 12v led ring switches from one 12v supply

Tags: led, switches, dc, 12v

I am new to electronics and general electronic circuits. I have 4+ led ring switches (from here: [follow link](https://www.switchelectronics.co.uk/red-led-on-on-latching-22mm-vandal-resistant-push-switch-spst))

The website says that the rating of the switch contacts is 5A 250VAC with an illumination voltage of 12V

I am unsure as to how to wire the switches together from one socket.

I currently have a 12V DC plug adapter that I am using to power one single switch.

As the switch requires the power to turn on LEDs, would it be that the high amperes would damage the components within the circuit?

The adapter I am using gives this information:

input: 230V~50Hz 300mA
output: 12V 1500mA

Since each switch will require 12V (as stated on the product page) will I be able to wire the switches as such in the image below? (with red being positive and blue being negative) Or will I have to use multiple power sources to power a few switches at a time?

The diagram below shows the adapter (bottom left) with the 4 12v switches, the wires go to the positive and negative terminal on each switch

[image: wiring design]

Comment: Please draw a diagram with a switch, show the adapter information, and show what the device is.

Comment: There is already a diagram with my question? I have added the adapter information. What device are you refering to?

Comment: Can the power supply support four times the current of the LED module?

Comment: @Hearth The website for the switch does not specify anything other than that it has a 12V illumination voltage. So I am not able to work out the current of the LED as there is not other data for me to be able to transpose

Comment: Then we can't answer this question, because the limiting factor is how much current the supply can provide compared to how much the LEDs consume. If you're that dedicated, you could always measure it.

Comment: With your comment I am going to be able to calculate the maximum number of switches that can be supported by the power supply adapter. I have emailed the company enquiring as the current required by the LEDs. Are you able to convert your comment to an answer so that I may close this question? @Hearth

Comment: If you have a multimeter, you can use it to measure the current required by the lights in the switches.  I'd guess  the LED current would be under 20 mA (but that's only a wild guess) - if so, your supply could drive the LEDs in  about 75 switches.

Comment: I agree with Peter but suggest the LED probably only needs 5mA these days for a switch luminaire

Comment: the switch contacts have nothing to do with the LED illumination

Answer (score 0):

After contacting the website about the amperes of the ring LED. 25mA

So therefore if my supply can handle 1500mA, 4 x 25mA = 100mA which is well within the rating of the supply.

Many thanks to @Hearth and @peter-bennett